# Complex Condition in Database Trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

```
Table1 contains id(Auto PK), Key(Varchar) & Value(Int)
Table2 contains Key(Varchar), postive_sum(Int), negative_sum(Int)
```

We need to write a trigger whenever a new row is inserted in Table1

- It should compare the newly inserted value(newRow.Table1.Value) with previous value (oldRow.Table1.Value) for the same Key
- If it is greater, Table2's positive_sum field has
  to be updated by adding newly inserted value(newRow.Table1.Value)
  with existing value
- If it is lesser, Table2's negative_sum field has
  to be updated by adding newly inserted value(newRow.Table1.Value)
  with existing value
- If key on table2 does not exists ,a the corresponding record has to be created

We have tried with the required logics but we lacks more on creating the same in MS SQL Server 2008.

Any inputs would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, does the "key" already exists on `Table2`?, or do you have to first check existance on that table to do an `INSERT` and then an `UPDATE`?

Comment: What part don't you understand or do you just expect someone to write a complete trigger for you?

Answer (score 0):

Note: as there might be more Table1 records updated at the same time having the same key  one must sum the differences putting only the summary weight to positive and negative summary fields. Trying to do this without summation would fail because only the last row having the same key will be recorded and the rest discarded.

```
alter trigger theTrigger on Table1
after update, insert
as
    set NoCount ON

    if update(Value)
    begin
        -- Add missing records to summary table
        insert into table2 (Key, positive_sum, negative_sum)
         select distinct Key, 0, 0
           from Inserted
          where not exists (select null from table2 t2 where t2.Key = Inserted.Key)
        -- Update summary
        update table2
           set Positive_sum = isnull(positive_sum, 0) + isnull (diff.Positives, 0),
               Negative_sum = isnull(Negative_sum, 0) + isnull (diff.Negatives, 0)
          from table2
        -- One can have only one record per key because otherwise sums would not be correct.
           inner join (select Inserted.Key, 
                          sum (case when Inserted.Value > isnull(Deleted.Value, 0) then Inserted.Value - isnull(Deleted.Value, 0) end) Positives,
                          sum (case when Inserted.Value < isnull(Deleted.Value, 0) then isnull(Deleted.Value, 0) - Inserted.Value end) Negatives,
                         from Inserted 
                              left join Deleted on Inserted.ID = Deleted.ID
                         group by Inserted.Key
                       ) diff
            on table2.Key = diff.Key

    end
```